# Binding to DependencyProperty of DependencyObject doesnt update

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a custom `DependencyObject` with a registered `DependencyProperty`  When I attempt to bind this to another `DependencyProperty` nothing happens, it never updates

```
class MyDepObj : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty CancelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Cancel", typeof(bool), typeof(MyDepObj), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCancelChanged)));

    private static void OnCancelChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Never gets called
    }
    public bool Cancel
    {
        get{return (bool)GetValue(CancelProperty);}
        set{SetValue(CancelProperty, value);}
    }
}

.....

{
    PropertyPath IsPressed = new PropertyPath("IsPressed", null);  //<-*EDIT* Was located outside of quoted code
    MyDepObj do = new MyDepObj();
    Binding b = new Binding();
    b.Source = MyButton;
    b.Path = IsPressed;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(do, MyDepObj.CancelProperty, b);
}
```

As a test I created an extension of `Grid` and attached the same `DependencyProperty` and did the binding in xaml.  That worked fine, I dont know if the issue is my binding or the `DependencyObject`, There are no errors thrown it just doesnt update

Comment: Besides that `MyDepObj do` and `b.Path = IsPressed` will not compile, this code just works. Show us how you are *actually* trying to use it.

Comment: Sorry `IsPressed` was declared outside the scope I quoted.  This is how I am actually trying to use it.  I created a demo app with just this to rule all other stuff out

Comment: Why not `new PropertyPath("IsPressed")` without the `null` argument?

Comment: I just tried that, no difference

Comment: Can't tell anything more. As said, it works fine for me.